# How does an index's fill factor relate to a query plan?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sql-execution-plan

When a PostgreSQL query's execution plan is generated, how does an index's fill factor affect whether the index gets used in favor of a sequential scan?

A fellow dev and I were reviewing the performance of a PostgreSQL (12.4) query with a windowed function of `row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY x, y, z)` and seeing if we could speed it up with an index on said fields. We found that during the course of the query the index would get used if we created it with a fill factor >= 80 but not at 75. This was a surprise to us as we did not expect the fill factor to be considered in creating the query plan.

If we create the index at 75 and then insert rows, thereby packing the pages > 75, then once again the index gets used. What causes this behavior and should we consider it when selecting an index's fill factor on a table that will have frequent inserts and deletes and be periodically vacuumed?

Comment: You should be updating to the latest minor release.

Answer (score 1):

> If we create the index at 75 and then insert rows, thereby packing the pages > 75, then once again the index gets used.

So, it is not the fill factor, but rather the size of the index (which is influenced by the fill factor).  This agrees with my memory that index size is a (fairly weak) influence on the cost estimate.  That influence is almost zero if you are reading only one tuple, but larger if you area reading many tuples.
If the cost estimates of the plan are close to each other, then small differences such as this will be enough to drive one over the other.  But that doesn't mean you should worry about them.  If one plan is clearly superior to the other, then you should think about why the estimates are so close together to start with when the realities are not close together.